# Impossible to connect a windows mongodb container when --auth is enabled

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker

First, sorry for my bad english ^^

I have launch a windows mongodb with a volume attached.

```
docker run -d -v mongovol:c:\data\db mongo:4.0-windowsservercore
```

Then, the connexion between my computer and the mongodb-container was perfect and i 
And I was able to create an admin user

```
use admin
db.createUser(
{
user: "admin",
pwd: "password",
roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, 
         { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, 
         { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
}
)
```

Then, i shutdown my mongodb and relaunch it with the --auth flag to enabled the authorisation.

After that, nothing else goes, when I try to connect to the database with(in my computer mongo installation)

```
mongo 172.28.221.45:27017/admin -u admin -p password
```

(The ip-adress is the IP of my container)

Im getting this error-message :

> MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
>   connecting to: mongodb://172.28.221.45:27017/admin
>   2018-10-24T11:00:20.161+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 172.28.221.45:27017, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error connecting to 172.28.221.45:27017 :: caused by :: Socket operation timed out :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
>   @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

After multiple searches, I did not find any functional solutions

thank you in advance :)

Julien.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need expose port -p 27017:27017

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -d -v mongovol:c:\data\db mongo:4.0-windowsservercore
```

Comment: Im getting the same problem but that was a good idea. When i Launching the docker in interactive mode I noticed that it is cut after an internal error message:  exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file: C:\data\db\mongod.lock (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.). Ensure the user executing mongod is the owner of the lock file and has the appropriate permissions. Also make sure that another mongod instance is not already running on the C:\data\db\ directory, terminating

Comment: If you try to connect from another host to mongodb container you need to expose out the port

did you try?

Comment: Thanks ! It's worked fine with the --bin_ip_all flag

Answer (score 0):

Wonderfull ! Its worked ! Thanks you Meiram !
The complete solution :

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -d -v mongovol:c:\data\db mongo:4.0-windowsservercore mongod --auth --bind_ip_all
```

And make sure that no others instance of the mongodb server its running